# Having trouble with a query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Let's say I've got a SQL Server table that logs user activity. Let's say it has user ID, user name, activity date, and activity type columns. I want to print out a list of all user activity, with one row for each month of activity, and a column for each activity type summing up the number of times that activity occurred in that month. I'm trying to do this with the following query:

```
 SELECT 
    user_id, 
    user_name, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), activity_date, 120),
    SUM(CASE WHEN activity_type = 'Log In' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN activity_type = 'Save Document' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN activity_type = 'Create Document' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM UserActivity
    WHERE DATE BETWEEN '11-1-2010 00:00:00' AND '12-31-2010 23:59:59'
GROUP BY user_id, user_name, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), activity_date, 120)
```

The problem is, this query is essentially giving me a separate row for each activity--lots and lots of rows, no counting. I think that the problem is with the way I'm doing the dates, because if I change the query to not select the date, I get a table that looks "mostly correct."

Any thoughts?

Comment: What @JNK is saying is that you need a GROUP BY user_id, user_name, activity_date

Comment: list some rows of output showing the "separate rows". FWIW a good idea to state which SQL Server version in questions, such as adding a sql-server-2005 tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a SUM without a GROUP BY, at least not with other non-aggregates in the SELECT. Do your GROUP BY clause properly.

```
SELECT 
user_id, 
user_name, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), activity_date, 120),
SUM(CASE WHEN activity_type = 'Log In' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN activity_type = 'Save Document' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN activity_type = 'Create Document' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM UserActivity
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '11-1-2010 00:00:00' AND '12-31-2010 23:59:59'
GROUP BY user_id, 
user_name, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), activity_date, 120)
```

For what it's worth, for date ranges, I prefer to use

```
WHERE DATE >= '20101101'
  AND DATE <  '20110101'
```

I'm sure losing a few records with a timestamp of '12-31-2010 23:59:59.997' won't matter, but it's just more logically correct to use a `< next_date` test.  And to be pedantic, the format YYYYMMDD is the most robust regardless of regional/language/dateformat settings.

Comment: I added a GROUP BY to my original question. The query I'm using does have a GROUP BY, I just forgot to add it to this question. The basic problem persists, though.

Comment: I TAKE IT ALL BACK! So, I had plain ol' activity_date in my GROUP BY, but was modifying activity_date in the SELECT statement. I needed to do the same convert in my GROUP BY that I was doing in my SELECT. Good catch. Thanks!